# Sumologic dashboard configuration as code

Tags: sumologic

I have a set of Sumologic searches, alerts, and dashboards set up, all done manually in the Sumologic web UI.

In line with the [observability as code](https://www.thoughtworks.com/radar/techniques) pattern, would it be possible to achieve the same using API calls, rather than clicking in the GUI? (Yesterday I made some changes to our searches, and am wondering if and how I could revert to the previous state. If our set-up was versioned in git, this would be easy.)